# jgeometry cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: oracle, geometry, prepared-statement, spatial

I try to get a sdo_geometry from a Oracle Database, but I am not able to do that.
Here is my code:

```
try {
    rs = preStatement.executeQuery("SELECT shape FROM "+table+" where id=0");
    STRUCT st = (oracle.sql.STRUCT) rs.getObject(1);
    JGeometry j_geom = JGeometry.load(st);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get an error "JGeometry cannot be resolved to a type".
But Eclipse don't offer me to import a library :(

I have a ojdbc14.jar-driver in my BuildPath and other jdbc-stuff is working fine.
Has somebody an idea what is wrong here ?

Gruß, Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the sdoapi.jar file in your class path, and import oracle.spatial.JGeometry.

The sdoapi.jar file is in $ORACLE_HOME/md/jlib

Comment: I recommend using Hibernate Spatial - it supports loading/saving between SDO_GEOMETRY / JtsGeometry and the JAR's are in Maven Central so it's easy to setup.